# Insert Div at the top of a page, shifting everything down after inserted Div

Tags: javascript, jquery, userscripts, tampermonkey

I have a userscript that adds a navigation bar to Google similar to the one they had a few years back.
The way I have the script set up now I have to hard code CSS code for each site that it matches in order for my bar to be at the top of the page, and to shift everything down.

```
else if (/google.{2,6}forms/.test(vCurrentWebpage) == true ||
    /google.{2,6}slides/.test(vCurrentWebpage) == true ||
    /google.{2,6}sheets/.test(vCurrentWebpage) == true ||
    /google.{2,6}docs/.test(vCurrentWebpage) == true ||
    /google.{2,6}services/.test(vCurrentWebpage) == true ||
    /google.{2,6}cloudprint/.test(vCurrentWebpage) == true
) {
    GM_addStyle(`
    body{position:relative!important;
         top:29px!important;}
    .header,.stickyMobileHeader .mobileSearchWrapper,.mobileNavHeader{top:29px!important;}

    #GoogleBar{position:fixed!important;}
    `);
```

This method does work for most sites, but for sites with a fixed element on the bottom, **the bottom element gets cut off**:

[image: With my bar the bottom element gets cut off]

But, **the bottom element should be completely visible**:

[image: good bottom]

Is there a more reliable way to insert an element at the top of the page?

I've searched, and searched but I can't seem to figure this one out myself.

[Here's a link to my full code](https://greasyfork.org/en/scripts/29660-googlebarreturns2017/code)

Comment: There is no "one size fits all" way to do this unless you are willing to float your bar over the top of the page (perhaps translucent until moused over).  Or, you can embed the actual page in an iframe (a PITA with many Google pages).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

- Short Answer: you can't (in an elegant way)
- Long Answer: you still can't because google calculates the height of the elements based on the visual-height of the window, and not of the relative parents, meaning that doesn't matter the technique you can't affect the calculation that is inserted as inline-style to the page. but you still have other UX tricks to do that like a button that opens your menu and overlaps for a moment the real menu.

but...

you can affect the element that controls the height with a hacky js

```
// for google spreadsheets go to the console and try
var grid = $('.grid-table-container + .grid-table-container')
grid.style.height = parseInt(grid.style.height, 10) - 30 + 'px'
```

that will give you enough space to put something at the top and remember to `transform: translateY(##)` the body instead of the `top` prop that you have

Comment: Well, that is unfortunate.

It makes perfect sense on why I can't, so thank you for explaining that in detail.  I went and put that into the console and it did work, however the horizontal scroll bar then becomes hidden. I think my best option here is to just not allow this userscript to run on Google Sheets since I don't think I can reliably adjust all the elements accordingly.  

And definitely thanks for the Transform option, completely forgot that even existed!